# GeometryReader behaves oddly with an extracted view

Tags: swiftui, geometryreader

In this example, the "hello" text is placed in the middle of the screen, as expected.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            Text("hello")
                .background(Color.green)
        }
        .background(Color.blue)
    }
}
```

But when I move `Text` to an extracted view, the "hello" text moves to the top left corner of the screen.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            ExtractedView()
        }
        .background(Color.blue)
    }
}

struct ExtractedView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("hello")
            .background(Color.green)
    }
}
```

Is this a bug, or an expected behavior I don't understand?

Comment: Can't reproduce with Xcode 11.5, iOS 13.5 (SwiftUI 1.0).

Comment: @pawello2222 I'm on Xcode 11.6. What do you see with Xcode 11.5?

Comment: In both cases the same: the text "hello" with a green background and a blue background for the rest of the view.

Comment: @pawello2222 in both cases the "hello" is centered?

Comment: Yes, in both cases.

Comment: @pawello2222 thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirm top-left location on Xcode 12 / iOS 14. I don't think it is a bug. Actually, `GeometryReader` is not a container and does not (should not) have own default alignment, its purpose custom alignment, so here we are.

Possible solutions (tested with Xcode 12b3 / iOS 14):

1. place by position

```
GeometryReader { geo in
    ExtractedView()
        .position(x: geo.size.width / 2, y: geo.size.height / 2)
}
```

2. wrap into full-size stack container (that has default alignment)

```
GeometryReader { geo in
    VStack {
        ExtractedView()
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. But if it's not a container, why does it behave like one in my first example? What's the difference between using something directly vs in an extracted view?